# Select text between several different kinds of tags in javascript by using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, select, text, tags

I am trying to code some stuff in HTML, CSS and Javascript.
I have some problems with regex.

Let me take a simple example to explain my problem because I can't find the solution.

```js
<script>
var str = "I am <b>a tennis player</b> but  I like also playing <i>football</i> and <i>rugby</i>, I am  <b>34</b> years old, I like <u>cooking</u> even if there is nothing in common with <i>tennis</i>, <i>football</i> or <i>rugby</i>.";

var result = str.match(/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/g).map(function(val){
   return val.replace(/<\/?b>/g,'');
});

alert(result)

</script>
```

So as you may have guessed it, I am looking for selecting all the text between the tags `<b></b>,<i></i>,<u></u>`. To be clearer I want to be able to select "`a tennis player`", "`football`", "`rubgy`", "`34`", "`cooking`" etc.

For the moment, I managed to deal with only one tag. When I try with several ones I fail. I have no experience on regex (I didn't study and work in this field) and the courses I found on the internet didn't answer my question. I don't think it is difficult to combine three regex, but I am lost with clast, with AND or OR etc. :/

Comment: When you parse HTML, use a HTML parser.

Comment: @Tushar Not yet :s I need to learn what's jQuery is precisely (I heard sth about it but not with an accurate view)

Comment: @stribizhev oh I didn't find know this then I will google it :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See code below:

```js
var str = "I am <b>a tennis player</b> but  I like also playing <i>football</i> and <i>rugby</i>, I am  <b>34</b> years old, I like <u>cooking</u> even if there is nothing in common with <i>tennis</i>, <i>football</i> or <i>rugby</i>.";

var result = str.match(/<(b|i|u)>(.*?)<\/\1>/g).map(function(val){
   return val.replace(/<\/?b>|<\/?i>|<\/?u>/g,'');
});

alert(result)
```

Comment: I think you 'd better write it as `<([biu])>(.*?)<\/\1>`. Safer. Or if you want to  preserve the structure for multicharacter tags, use `<(b|i|u)>(.*?)<\/\1>`. Well, why replace inside a match at all? Just use `RegExp#exec` that keeps all submatches.

Comment: @stribizhev thanks for your suggestions. First part is clear for me and i've updated code...but not sure that i understand second suggestion with `RegExp#exec` (

Comment: Tushar has undeleted his answer, have a look what I meant.

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko Hi :D it's me again ! So it helped me a lot to automatize some parts I do every day but it works only for strings I think as when I try to apply the same function to a textArea for instance (a small article I wrote for which I added so tags) nothing appends .... do you have a tips to solve it ? :D

(by text I mean : an article I wrote and that I copy and paste in a textArea of a small simple editor I coded)

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko humm in fact when the whole text is in one line it works I have the feeling ... then maybe  I just need to make the white space become inactive  no ?

Comment: @Studentin: You will have more and more headache with regex parsing HTML - why bother?

Comment: @stribizhev Hey I managed to solve my problem :D and I find it wasn't so complicated with regex.


. Now as I will have time today I will try your solution with RegExp#exec and maybe I will also start studying serioulsy JQuery also !

Comment: For `u`, `b` and `i` it might be more or less easy, but it will be much harder with tags with attributes especially when you want to match nested tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following regex to extract the innerText of elements.

```
/<([biu])>(.*?)<\/\1>/gi
```

**Explanation:**

1. `<([biu])>`: Matches `<` followed by either `b`/`i`/`u` and then `>`. Can also be written as `<(b|i|u)>` and puts the tagName in the first captured group.
2. `(.*?)`: Non-greedy match. Matches as many as possible characters to satisfy the condition
3. `<\/\1>`: Matches the `</` followed by the first captured group(see #1 above) followed by `>`. Thus matching the closing tag.
4. `gi`: g: Global flag to match all possible results. `i`: Case-insensitive match.

```js
var str = "I am <b>a tennis player</b> but  I like also playing <i>football</i> and <i>rugby</i>, I am  <b>34</b> years old, I like <u>cooking</u> even if there is nothing in common with <i>tennis</i>, <i>football</i> or <i>rugby</i>.";

var regex = /<([biu])>(.*?)<\/\1>/gi,
    result = [];

while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
    result.push(match[2]);
}

console.log(result);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

---

You can also use jQuery.

```js
var str = "I am <b>a tennis player</b> but  I like also playing <i>football</i> and <i>rugby</i>, I am  <b>34</b> years old, I like <u>cooking</u> even if there is nothing in common with <i>tennis</i>, <i>football</i> or <i>rugby</i>.";

var result = [];

$('<div/>').html(str).find('b, i, u').each(function(i, e) {
    result.push(e.innerText);
});
console.log(result);
$('body').html('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You always have great demos :)

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks! It's your comment on other answer, that make me undelete this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Getting all text from `u`, `b` and `i`  tags can be easily achieved with plain JS DOM parser:

```js
function getTagTexts(str, tag) {
  var el = document.createElement( 'html' ); // create an empty element
  el.innerHTML = '<faketag>' + str + '</faketag>';  // init the innerHTML property of the element
  var arr = [];  // declare the array for the results
  [].forEach.call(el.getElementsByTagName(tag), function(v,i,a) { // iterate through the tags we want
      arr.push(v.innerText);  // and add the innerText property to the array
  });
  return arr;
}

var txt = "I am <b>a tennis player</b> but  I like also playing <i>football</i> and <i>rugby</i>, I am  <b>34</b> years old, I like <u>cooking</u> even if there is nothing in common with <i>tennis</i>, <i>football</i> or <i>rugby</i>.";

var arrayI = getTagTexts(txt, "i");
var arrayU = getTagTexts(txt, "u");
var arrayB = getTagTexts(txt, "b");
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(arrayI, 0, 4) + "<br/>"; // => ["football", "rugby", "tennis", "football", "rugby"]
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(arrayU, 0, 4) + "<br/>"; // => ["cooking"]
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(arrayB, 0, 4); // => ["a tennis player", "34"]
```

Note that the `faketag` is necessary if you need to parse an HTML fragment without `html`/`body`  tags.

Comment: Basically, this is same as my answer using jQuery. +1 for plain JS solution.

Comment: What is funniest, I even did not see your answer when writing mine and that comment.